# Horse missing after reloading

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In the Epilogue, I dismounted well outside of Shady Belle to avoid my horse getting injured in the fight.

I got killed in the gunfight but, when my game reloaded, my horse had been replaced with a Tennessee Walker.

I figured it was a glitch since my horse was not harmed in the battle.  So I went to Saint Denis stables to retrieve my horse and -- sure enough -- it's not there.

It's annoying because there's no logical reason why the game would kill my horse in that situation.

I'd love some feedback on this specific issue.

Comment: What kind of "feedback" are you looking for?

Comment: Is this a known issue?  
Should your primary horse vanish from the game just because your character dies?
Can this be prevented in the future?

Comment: If you reload an earlier save, is the horse there? If you only auto-save and never manually save, you're kinda screwed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug, pure and simple.

If you google this, you'll find 100s of posts about it and R* hasn't addressed it yet since some posts are as old as just a few days ago.

There's not much you can do honestly. Apart from **saving**, **manually** and saving **often**. Manually saving every new mission or after a major event in the game saved my butt from multiple horse-killing random encounters.

Also, your horse is safer from bugs if you dismount and make it flee during a mission than dismounting and entering a mission on foot. As long as you can see it on the mini-map, the glitch monster can't get it.